# Ubuntu setup fails everytime

Tags: 16.04, system-installation, usb, 17.04, 17.10

I have tried installing Ubuntu 16.04, 17.04 and 17.10. All of them show the same, "Ubuntu has experience an internal error" message. I have tried it with different USB sticks and still the same result. I have also tried different softwares for creating the USB setup and still no difference.

Comment: What hardware are you attempting to install it on?

Comment: @vidarlo Dell Inspiron 5559. It was running fine on it till now.